# Flashing Stock Android ROM from another country

Tags: device-firmware

I purchased my SM-A520F from UAE. I am currently using the phone in India.

All Samsung Mobiles sold in UAE have VOLTE disabled by default, and hence my phone do not have it. However, majority of the 4G carriers in India use VOLTE and this causes problems that are not minor.

Rooting the phone will probably void warranty. I was told that I can flash stock firmware for this device released for India without having to root.

1. Will this void warranty?
   I contacted customer support of Samsung UAE and they told me it would. But I dont believe them since sources on the internet say otherwise and I won't be rooting the phone.
2. If I were to go ahead with this, where can I get the official firmware? Is there any option to download this from Samsung website?
3. What is knox counter? Will I be able to do this without "tripping" knox?
4. Once I download and install stock firmware from a different country from a  website like Sammobile.com can I still receive OTA updates?
5. After flashing a firmware downloaded from a third party website, how safely can I use applications that use sensitive data like S Pay and mobile banking applications?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-to-flash-stock-ROM-of-another-country-on-Samsung-devices

Comment: 1. Yes, it will void the warranty; 2. Hard to say, some Samsung firmwares are available "officially", some are leaked, and some are not available at all. XDA forums for you device are the best place to look; 3. KNOX counter is a way of checking if you phone is or has been modified, in theory flashing a stock ROM will NOT trip the Knox counter; 4. Probably; 5. If you are stock, you are stock, the source of the image isn't relevant since the image will be digitally signed.... The real issue here is the hardware/radio differences that cannot be edited or flashed, it likely will not function right

Comment: @acejavelin, post this as answer

Comment: @acejavelin I would like to know how it will void the warranty. If I were to flash the UAE version of the firmware back before sending it to the service center, is there any way of knowing whether I flashed a different firmware in the first place? Especially when flashing won't trip knox?

Comment: @RanaPrathap You are modifying the device... No different than if I took my US device and tried to get a warranty replacement when it had Indian firmware, it immediately red flags the device as modified.

Comment: My question is if I flash the original UAE firmware on it before sending it to the service center, will they be able to know whether I modified it?

Comment: Would they know? Maybe, there are other methods available to the manufacturer to check if the device has been modified besides Knox if they chose to do so. Remember the average modern Android device has 25+ partitions, of which we can only access about 6, the rest is proprietary or encrypted information, the question is would they? There is also no guarantee that the bootloader or ODIN will even let you flash a different ROM because the variant or product code may not match.

Comment: And BTW, the chances India's VoLTE radio firmware will work on your device and carrier is near zero... the firmware for India that supports Jio is proprietary to that carrier, it is not "generic" VoLTE like US and European carriers use.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it will void the warranty;
2. Hard to say, some Samsung firmwares are available "officially", some are leaked, and some are not available at all. XDA forums for you device are the best place to look;
3. KNOX counter is a way of checking if you phone is or has been modified, in theory flashing a stock ROM will NOT trip the Knox counter;
4. Probably;
5. If you are stock, you are stock, the source of the image isn't relevant since the image will be digitally signed....

The real issue here is the hardware/radio differences that cannot be edited or flashed, it likely will not function right, that information is protected and tied to the device, flashing a ROM does not change bands or network connectivity of the hardware, but it does change the radio firmware which can cause a mismatch of hardware capability to radio firmware preventing connectivity.